# RDP through Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, rdp

This is a R&D project. Stream Windows PC's desktop to mobile phone on Bluetooth. I am successful in streaming desktop to my Android phone with 720p but the thing is I am unable to get live stream. Encoding and Data going over Bluetooth take some milliseconds, so it is not that live. So what I did, I chose RDP for this. As RDP is only built for LAN. I have no profile for PAN. I wrote a proxy which only routes RDP packets from localhost to my computer over bluetooth. On Computer side there is another program running which takes data from bluetooth and sends this data to localhost port 3389. Now the problem I am facing is that, as connection initiated, socket gets close itself. The program only reads 80 or 45 bytes initially, then exception occurs "Socket Closed". My question is, does RDP open and close sockets for a session, or connects for the first time and then use that socket. As I am new to this RDP thing. suggest me some topic about RDP. Any help is highly appreciated.

regards
Moonzai

UPDATE:

I am using following code for reading and writting to and from Bluetooth and Socket.

```
  class ReadWrite implements Runnable {

    private String name;

    private Thread thread;
    private InputStream is;
    private OutputStream os;

    private volatile boolean start = false;

    public ReadWrite(String name, InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
        this.name = name;
        this.is = is;
        this.os = os;
        thread = new Thread(this);
    }

    public void startThread() {
        start = true;
        thread.start();
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        start = false;
        try {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }

            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(name + " ReadWrite Started");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8092];
        int read;

        while (start) {
            try {
                read = is.read(buffer);
                System.out.println(name + " Read: " + read);
                if (read > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    os.flush();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(name + " ReadWrite Stopped");
    }
}
```

I am starting 2 instances of this thread like:

```
  ReadWrite bt2net = new ReadWrite("bt2net", btis, netos);
  ReadWrite net2bt = new ReadWrite("net2bt", netis, btos);
  bt2net.startThread();
  net2bt.startThread();
```

where `btis`, `netos`, `netis` and `btos` are `InputStream` and `OutputStream`. This class is used on both sides Android and PC. PC side runs with read length of -1 whereas Android side gives me this exception:

```
  java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
  java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1
```

I dont what and why this is happening. Please put some light on RDP low level, as I didn't find any helpful information.

Comment: Great work btw for the project :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like RDP does open and close sockets when connecting. I just did a packet capture of an RDP connection from a Windows Vista computer to a Windows Server 2003 R2 server, and there are two TCP streams. The first TCP stream consists of 19 bytes one way, then 19 bytes back the other way, similar to how you describe. A second later, another TCP connection is set up, and this lasts the length of the session.

Good luck with your project!